# SQL query to print part of string value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have text field in MySQL 5.6 table which consists string representation of JSON.
Such JSONs exist field "clients" with array of ID's, e.g.:

```
{
    ...
    "clients":[1,2,3],
    ...
}
```

How to write SQL query which prints exactly this part of text from JSON for every record, e.g.:

```
clients
-----------------
"clients":[1,2,3]
"clients":[4,5]
...
```

Should I use some kind of regex or it could be done easier?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**: JSON_EXTRACT doesn't work for MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Don't* use regex to parse JSON, instead use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.clients")
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Using regex to parse JSON is generally a bad idea unless there is no alternative.  In this case, more recent versions of MySQL offer a JSON API which can handle your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for quick response! The difficulty is that type of data is "text", not "json" and I can't change it, so that I have to handle it as a plain string

Comment: This should not matter, and if you view the demo, you will see that the JSON functions can also operate on plain text, so long as that plain text be valid JSON.

Comment: *"I have text field in MySQL 5.6 table which consists string representation of JSON"* One problem i believe MySQL 5.6 does not support native JSON functions or does not have great JSON support, the more modern 5.6 versions might have it

Comment: Seems like it doesn't work for MySQL 5.6 :(  [42000][1305] FUNCTION authdb.JSON_EXTRACT does not exist

Comment: @DmitryAdonin If so, then it also means you won't have any regex support, in which case you may not be able to handle JSON well with your version of MySQL.  If you have a long term need to manipulate JSON in MySQL, then consider upgrading to a more recent version.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But could I do smth like "get string starting from "clients":[ until first ]"?

Comment: ""get string starting from "clients":[ until first ]"" @DmitryAdonin see mine answer, it will run on MySQL 5.6 without JSON / REGEX functions

Comment: Yes, you _could_ try to do that.  But keep in mind as soon as your JSON structure changes, your query could break.  Also appreciate that the order of fields in JSON can move around without changing the logical equivalence of the JSON.

Comment: This data isn't being changed, also seems like no matter where is "clients":[...] placed in JSON if I search tokens, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Well i strongly advice upgrading, this query is more meant for fun.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 DISTINCT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        records.cvs
      , ','
      , number_generator.number
    )
    , ','
    , -1
  ) array_part
FROM (
 SELECT 
 @row := @row + 1 AS number
FROM (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @row := 0 
) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN (


SELECT 
  # parse out the 1,2,3 part from  [1,2,3] part
  SUBSTRING (
     # parse out the [1,2,3] part
     SUBSTRING(
         records.json
       , (LOCATE(':', records.json) + 1)
     )
   , 2 
   , LENGTH(
      # parse out the [1,2,3] part
      SUBSTRING(
         records.json
       , (LOCATE(':', records.json) + 1)
       )
     ) - 2
 ) AS cvs
FROM (
  SELECT  
    '"clients":[1,2,3]' AS json
) AS records

) AS records
```

**Result**

```
| array_part |
| ---------- |
| 1          |
| 2          |
| 3          |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pdCZQK95C4Fe6wU6mVxySR/0)

Comment: Looks a bit complicated, I just need to cut "clients":[...] slice from string, I started from "select substr(json, instr(json, '"clients":['))" but stucked how to get index of first ] symbol after "clients":[

Comment: indeed @DmitryAdonin that's why you should upgrade.  i use SUBSTRING in combination with LOCATE to parse out the json array part and a SQL number generator to parse the `1,2,3` string into real records with nested STRING_INDEX functions.

Comment: also @DmitryAdonin why don't you play around with the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pdCZQK95C4Fe6wU6mVxySR/0) and make it more [simple](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pdCZQK95C4Fe6wU6mVxySR/0) to see what the parts are doing?

Comment: It's a shame but I don't understand half of this example :)

Answer (score 1):

Must be processed from SQL? I think it is more rational to process outside SQL server.
Or you can upgrade your MySQL to 5.7.8+ and use JSON_EXTRACT.
Everything else will be a BIG crutch.